# Change the click event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think this seems to be a quite common question, but since I am new to J Query, I couldn't understand other solutions, so thought to put my problem and be specific.

I have an anchor tag:

```
<a href="#" id="isActive" onclick="javascript: toggleThisDiv(this.id);" style="float: left;" title="Expand/Collapse">
<img src="arrow_down.gif" border="0">
</a>
```

When I click on it, it calls the javascript function which hides the existing div. Now after this, I want to change the anchor tag's click event, so that when I click on the same anchor again, it refreshes the page.

Thanks a lot in advance for any solution.

Comment: if you're using the onclick porperty, you don't need to specify `javascript:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function toggleThisDiv(id) {
    // do your other stuff in this function

    document.getElementById(id).onclick=function() {
        location.reload(true);
    };
}
```

Comment: i'm pretty sure that on first click, this will reload the page... which makes this wrong...

Comment: @Reigel: Nope. On first click, this changes the click handler to load the page, but it doesn't actually execute the change. The next click after that will, however.

Comment: no, the OP wants; 1st click should hide some divs; 2nd click should reload the page...

Comment: @Reigel: Indeed, that is what happens. I didn't include his other code in this function, but you can see that he should insert his code at my comment and leave the rest of the function as it is. On first click, this function hides his elements and changes the click handler. When the second click happens it executes the updated click handler, which will simply refresh the page.

Comment: yes. first click will hide one div and second should reload the page.

Comment: @Vishnu: Yep, that's what my answer will do. =)

Comment: and just to add, the OP doesn't need jQuery for doing this... well, just in this question of his..

Comment: @Reigel: Indeed, that's why I'm not using jQuery. :p Oh, and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("isActive").onclick = function();
```

Comment: This one worked...thanks a lot.... but i would have appreciated if I could have got the same code in jquery. I am new and not very comfortable with jquery coding format. But still thanks a lot to @ElliotBonneville.. you made my life much easier.

Comment: Ditto :) Sorry I couldn't help you out on that part, but glad you got it working!

Comment: I found it! `$('#isActive').click(function() {  });`

Comment: @VishnuRai: In many cases, using native functions is faster than jQuery, although not always as cross-browser compatible.